# Is there a CSS "haschildren" selector?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Is there a css selector I can use only if a child element exists?

Consider:

```
<div> <ul> <li></li> </ul> </div>
```

I would like to apply `display:none` to div only if it doesn't have at least one child `<li>` element.

Any selector I can use do this?

Comment: not possible with css, but possible with javascript

Comment: *Can* be done in pure CSS: `div:not(:empty) { display: none }`.

Comment: The linked duplicate seems deleted, so might be worth reopening. Today there's a new CSS rule: `:has()`

Comment: @Evert The linked duplicate still exists and even mentions the `:has()` rule.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ah weird, when I went here yesterday it wasn't being rendered correctly. Retracted my reopen vote.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the linked question is a duplicate. This question asks for how to select an element that does not have (at list one) child element (second part of question, the first part actually asks the opposite...) and the linked "duplicate" is about selecting element that has children. I asks about opposite things.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately that's not possible with CSS selectors.

Comment: Here's some background information: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: A simple "no" doesn't reflect the state of modern CSS. See Tim Medora's answer below.

Comment: it is very sad in 2021 

Answer (score 32):

Sort of, with `:empty` but it's limited.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ky4dA/3/

Even text nodes will cause the parent to not be deemed empty, so a UL inside the DIV would keep the DIV from being matched.

```
<h1>Original</h1>
<div><ul><li>An item</li></ul></div>

<h1>No Children - Match</h1>
<div></div>

<h1>Has a Child - No Match</h1>
<div><ul></ul></div>

<h1>Has Text - No Match</h1>
<div>text</div>

DIV {
 background-color: red;
 height: 20px;    
}

DIV:empty {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo

If you go the script route:

```
// pure JS solution
​var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ){
    if( divs[i].childNodes.length == 0 ){ // or whatever condition makes sense
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }        
}​
```

Of course, jQuery makes a task like this easier, but this one task isn't sufficient justification to include a whole libary.

Comment: `:empty` will behave more naturally (and helpfully) in the future. Once browsers implement Selectors Level 4, `:empty` will represent "an element that has no children except, optionally, document white space characters." https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo

Answer (score 5):

CSS does not (yet) have any parent rules unfortunately, the only way around it if you must apply it only parents that contain a specific child is with the Javascript, or more easily with a library of javascript called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Javascript can be written in a similair way to CSS in someways, for your example we would do something like this at the bottom of our HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('div:has(ul li)').css("color","red");
</script>
```

(For this you would need to include the jQuery library in your document, simply by putting the following in your `<head></head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i liked this one the most since it is very compact. I used it together with the not selector like: jQuery('.navbar-inner:not(:has(ul li))').css('display', 'none');

Answer (score 2):

If you use jquery, you can try out this function

```
jQuery.fn.not_exists = function(){
    return this.length <= 0;
}

if ($("div#ID > li").not_exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another option

```
$('div ul').each(function(x,r) {
    if ($(r).find('li').length < 1){
        $(r).css('display','block'); // set display none
    }
})
```