# Add css stylings to list item of only it has child

Tags: css, parent, styling

I have a list like below

```
 <ul>
  <li>
  <a></a>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <a></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to add an arrow using :after only if li has a ul tag inside with using only css. I have applied following css styling but problem is not solved.

```
ul li ul:parent:after {
   border: 5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 8px solid #522;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Are there any methods for achieve this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206935/css-selector-if-child-exist

Answer (score 0):

`:parent` selectors don't yet exist in CSS.  You can do what you are asking with the [:has()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_has.asp) selector in jQuery.

However, I don't think `:after` selector is quite what you are looking for either, as it would not come after the `li` text, but after the entire element,

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a>Outer Item</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>Inner Item</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </li> <-- :after would place arrow here
</ul>
```

Similar to this:

```
o Outer Item
    o Inner Item
<--
```

You could use Javascript or jQuery to add the arrow after the initial text, but I don't think there is a way to do that with just CSS.

You can get sort of close with this, but the arrow appears on a line between the parent item and the child list:

```
li > a:first-child + ul:before {
   border: 5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 8px solid #522;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/29kc1p1x/